# implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' - Failed to resolve: firebase-core/auth-15.0.0

Tags: android, firebase

In android studio, after adding Firebase authentication I got this error, `Failed to resolve: firebase-core-15.0.0`, `Failed to resolve: firebase-auth-15.0.0` I changed `v7:28.0.0` into `v7:28.+` but same error appears. I added Maven

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

but same error got.

Full build.gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.thisuri.blogzone"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
            }
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1:15.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'


}
```

What is the solution?

Comment: It is better if you post the full code of your app level gradle file so we can help you.

Comment: Please check similar question on SO, there are tons of answers, which can solve your problem.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit there weren't any solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1:15.0.0'
```

Into this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
```

When declaring a dependency you need to write the groupId, artifactId and version number.

Also check this:

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android